# asp.net ajax slideshow does not work if the play button is invisible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Following this sample of slideshow asp.net ajax:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/SlideShow/SlideShow.aspx

with this code snippet:

```
<ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="Image1" 
    SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" 
    AutoPlay="true" 
    ImageTitleLabelID="imageTitle"
    ImageDescriptionLabelID="imageDescription"
    NextButtonID="nextButton" 
    PlayButtonText="Play" 
    StopButtonText="Stop" 
    PreviousButtonID="prevButton" 
    PlayButtonID="playButton" 
    Loop="true" />
```

I dont want to set the slideshow to autoplay so I set: AutoPlay="false" and I want only two buttons: previous (prevButton) and next (nextButton) visible. Therefore, I made the button play visible: playButton with property: Visible="false" but then the slideshow does work properly.

How can I make the playButton invisible and the slideshow still work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the Visible property to false as this would make it not to be rendered on the page (I think). Instead, enclose the playButton in a div with `display:none;` something like this:

```
<div style="display:none;">
   <asp:button id="btnPLay" ... />
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**
You can easily implement the whole slideshow in very simple steps using javascript. [See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg9UR/)

Comment: @lcarus, do you know how can I make the two button next and previous invisible if there is no any images available? thanks in advance.

Comment: @devn No, unfortunately I don't know and I don't think it can be done from the markup alone (at least the docs don't mention it). But you could do this yourself very easily. See my jsfiddle for an example on how to do this entirely on javascript. If you need the images to be dynamic, simply make an ajax request to a web service and return all the list of images in one shot (this is what the "extender" actually does)